# Node app on AWS returning 503

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have an Hello World node app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('in the get /');
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!');
});
```

I've pushed this to my EC2 instance. I go to my url and the page is black. I see a 503 is coming back. Im seeing live Node logs and the app is going into app.get because I see 'in the get /' repeatedly.

I have 2 instances. The first is running Nginx and requests to example.net get redirected to https://www.example.net. I also have a Load Balancer listening which take requests to www.example.net and directing them to my Node instance.

Incidentally, every few seconds I see a new 'in the get /' line. So my app is getting hit repeatedly from God knows where. Could this be comething to do with getting 503 (which indicates server is busy)? Note: this worked fine yesterday.

**EDIT**
The app suddenly started returning "Hello World". I then restarted the app - making no code changes - and im back getting 503's again

Comment: Are you behind a load balancer? The repeating hits might be from the health check.

Comment: yes i am. ah ok, that must be it

Comment: shouldnt the health check flag something? its completely random as to when i get 503 and when i dont

Comment: According to the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http503 the ELB will return a 503 error if no instances are registered, or no registered instances are healthy. Is your ELB showing that you have healthy instances when this is happening? It makes perfect sense that you would see this for a minute after a restart if you only have one instance in the pool.

Comment: it really sounds like something is up with load balancer config

Comment: @MarkB Looks like you are right. Sometimes after it a restart, it fails. When I come back 10 mins later, its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ELB is detecting that your instance is unhealthy because it's down during a restart (Unhealthy Threshold). Then it has to pass the health check a certain number of times before it is healty again (Healthy Threshold). You can configure all this in the [ELB settings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-healthchecks.html).

I would decrease the Unhealthy Threshold if you only have one instance in your pool. And possibly decrease the HealthCheck Interval as well.

Comment: Out of context but I realized didn't registered target to my target group so I was having 503 service error.